# Why is ToUpperInvariant() faster than ToLowerInvariant()?

Tags: c#, string, optimization, clr, normalization

I read in CLR via C# by Jeffrey Richter that `String.ToUpperInvariant()` is faster than `String.ToLowerInvariant()`. He says that this is because the FCL uses ToUpperInvariant to normalise strings, so the method is ultra-optimised. Running a couple quick tests on my machine, I concur that `ToUpperInvariant()` is indeed slightly faster.

My question is if anybody knows how the function is actually optimised on a technical level, and/or why the same optimisations were not applied to `ToLowerInvariant()` as well.

---

**Concerning the "duplicate":** The proposed "duplicate" question really doesn't provide an answer to my question. I understand the benefits of using `ToUpperInvariant` instead of `ToLowerInvariant`, but what I would like to know is how/why `ToUpperInvariant` performs better. This point is not addressed in the "duplicate".

Comment: Looks like the job for your friendly ildasm or favorite decompiler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801508/what-is-wrong-with-tolowerinvariant

Comment: Both `ToUpperInvariant()` and `ToLowerInvariant()` end up calling `InternalChangeCaseString()`, so the magic must be some optimizations within (or in methods called by) that method.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, Romuku - Effectively when looking with the ReSharper decompiler InternalChangeCaseString is called, which is interesting because I suspected that both methods might end up calling some shared function. However because InternalChangeCaseString is implemented directly in the CLR, I guess there's not much hope of knowing exactly what optimisations they put in place which leads to this behaviour.

Comment: Maybe this is also of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297703/how-do-you-set-strings-to-uppercase-lowercase-in-unicode

Comment: What about [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801508/what-is-wrong-with-tolowerinvariant/2801656#2801656)?

Comment: Already referenced in the second comment ;). It doesn't explain how the optimisation is functionally done, which is what I'm interested in, and particularly why the optimisation was not applied to `ToLowerInvariant`. I'm starting to think that the only person who can answer this is with this level of detail is someone like @EricLippert who actually has an in-depth knowledge of the CLR.

Comment: They both go back to `InternalChangeCaseString()`. This is where you could dig deeper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is now easier to [read the CLR source which implements `InternalChangeCaseString`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/classlibnative/nls/nlsinfo.cpp#L2100), we can see that it mostly calls down to the Win32 function [`LCMapStringEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318702(v=vs.85).aspx). There appears to be no notes or any discussion on the performance of passing in `LCMAP_UPPERCASE` vs. `LCMAP_LOWERCASE` for the `dwMapFlags` parameter. Calling `InternalChangeCaseString` uses a flag `isToUpper` which, if `true` may result in better optimization by the compiler (or JITter), but since the call to `LCMapStringEx` has to setup a p/invoke call frame and the call itself has to do work, I'm not sure a lot of time is saved there.

Perhaps the recommendation is a hold over from some other implementation, but I can't see anything that would provide a significant speed advantage one way or the other.