# how to refactor code to return IsPalindrome

Tags: c#

using a mock c# question on https://www.testdome.com/t

I have coded

```
using System;

public class Palindrome
{
   public static bool IsPalindrome(string word)
        {
            string testWord = word;

            string first = word[0].ToString();
            string last = word[word.Length - 1].ToString();

            bool isPal = false;

            while (testWord.Length > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(testWord);

                if (first.ToLower() == last.ToLower())
                {
                    testWord = testWord.Remove(0,1);
                    testWord = testWord.Remove(testWord.Length - 1);

                    isPal = true;
                }

            }

            return isPal;
        }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Palindrome.IsPalindrome("Deleveled"));
    }
}
```

this code is working but it is failing me on 
lowercase words: time limit exceeded
various words: time limit exceeded.

What changes could I make to refactor the code to work faster?

Comment: Just off the top of my head (and maybe doesn't fit here) but perhaps consider just [reversing the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string) and testing that the `ToLower(result)` matches the `ToLower(input)`. Like 5 lines of code and no loops.

Comment: You loop forever if the first and last characters aren't equal.. add `else return false;` on that `if`.

Comment: Your problem is *not* perfomance but correctness.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I went with @JNevill If you want the points. add the answer and I will tick it

Comment: @John Note that `ToUpperInvariant` [should be better](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2801508/11683). ([Or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35713225/11683).) But ultimately, if you are okay with/allowed to allocate another reversed string, then you should be comparing it to the original with `String.Equals (s1, s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` instead of converting both strings to lower or upper case.

Answer (score 2):

No need to write multiple line of code, you can check Palindrome in one line,

Magic of Linq,

```
bool isPalindrome = str.SequenceEqual(str.Reverse());
```

If you want to ignore case then convert original string and reverse string to lower case and then check its sequence

```
    string str = "Madam";
    var strReverse = str.ToLower().Reverse();
    var isPalindrome = str.ToLower().SequenceEqual(strReverse);
```

---

Basically, Palindrome check is a check where actual string is equal to its reverse. When we check original string to reverse string that time we need *not* to travel till the end. We just need to check first letter with it's last and so on...

Here is non-Linq Palindrome check,

```
   public static bool IsPalindrome(string word)
    {
        string testWord = word;
        for(int i = 0; i < word.Length/2; i++)
        {
            if(char.ToLower(testWord[i]) != char.ToLower(testWord[testWord.Length - i - 1]))
               return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

POC : [. net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t3CVaN)

Comment: thanks for the reply but it wouldnt allow linq in this mock

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is immediately return if you find a non-match.