# How does toLowerCase() work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, lowercase

I understand that using that function will make an entire string all lowercase. However, I'm curious in the behind the scenes work. I can't find an explanation anywhere on how it works. Does it basically loop through every index in the string and check to see what the character is and if there is a lower case character available?

Comment: The answer to that is going to be implementation specific; some may just call down to a library to do the conversion for it.

Comment: [This page from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) also might help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general the best place to look for such information is the [ECMAScript specification](https://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.16):

> The following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Call CheckObjectCoercible passing the this value as its argument.
> 2. Let S be the result of calling ToString, giving it the this value as its argument.
> 3. Let L be a String where each character of L is either the Unicode lowercase equivalent of the corresponding character of S or the actual corresponding character of S if no Unicode lowercase equivalent exists.
> 4. Return L.
>
> For the purposes of this operation, the 16-bit code units of the Strings are treated as code points in the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane. Surrogate code points are directly transferred from S to L without any mapping.
>
> The result must be derived according to the case mappings in the Unicode character database (this explicitly includes not only the UnicodeData.txt file, but also the SpecialCasings.txt file that accompanies it in Unicode 2.1.8 and later).

Step 3 is the part you're really interested in. As you can see, the details of how "L" is produced are up to the implementation. If you're interested in going deeper the next place to look would be e.g. the [V8 engine](https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror) itself.

Comment: 3. doesn't really seem all that implementation specific - it references the very definite Unicode specification. Well, except for the fact that there are multiple Unicode versions, of course...

Comment: @Luaan - It doesn't specify how you get from `S` to `L`. It specifies what `L` should be but not how to get there.

Comment: I don't think you're reading that right - it explicitly says you map each of the characters in S to the equivalent lowercase character as per unicode rules (casing mappings) to L. How much simpler than a S[i] -> L[i] map can you get?

Comment: @Luaan , Maybe this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297703/how-do-you-set-strings-to-uppercase-lowercase-in-unicode answered the details you want.

Comment: @Luaan - Right, but that actual mapping is down to the implementation. All I'm trying to say is that the only real way to see what's happening at that level is to look at the code of the engine.

Comment: The actual mapping is down to the unicode version supported and nothing else (as long as we only consider conforming implementations, of course). The ECMAscript spec simply delegates the handling of uppercase vs. lowercase to Unicode, another well estabilished standard. The best you can argue is that different versions of Unicode will work differently for some characters - but that isn't really all that relevant to the question; the answer to OPs question is still "map one character after another using unicode case mapping tables".