# How can we create javascript methods like toLowerCase method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how Javascript methods work behind the scene.

First I created a variable using `var` keyword in the chrome's console and tried to add a method to it:

```
var name1 = 'SARA';
name1.toLowerCase();
```

the `name1` returns `sara`.

After this I tried to do the same thing using `let` keyword:

```
let name2 = 'SARA';
name2.toLowerCase();
```

And as expected we have `sara` again. BUT:

if I try to return name variables like this I get `undefined` for `name2` which is declared using `let` keyword!

```
let name2 = 'SARA';
window.myname
undefined
```

How does `toLowerCase` method work? if declaring a variable using `let` keyword makes it `undefined` in the window object, how it still works on this kind of data?!

Are Javascript methods like `toLowerCase` attached to window object?

Can we create new methods like `toLowerCase` which we can use in our codes?

For instance, is there any solution to create something like this:

```
var name3 = 'Sara is a pretty girl';
name3.addDotToEnd();
window.name3
'Sara is a pretty girl.'
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does toLowerCase() work in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596945/how-does-tolowercase-work-in-javascript)

Comment: "*is there any solution to create something like this*" - no, strings are immutable. You cannot change them in-place.

Comment: `window.myname` returns `undefined` because you haven't declared it at all. But assuming you meant `window.name2`, then it will return `undefined` due to scoping. It has absolutely nothing to do with `toLowerCase`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings inherit from `String.prototype`. Anything on `String.prototype` (or `Object.prototype`, which it inherits from) can be called on a string:

```js
console.log(String.prototype.hasOwnProperty('toLowerCase'));
```

To add a method which can be called on strings yourself, add a method to `String.prototype`:

```js
String.prototype.addDotToEnd = function() {
  return String(this) + '.';
};

var name3 = 'Sara is a pretty girl';
console.log(name3.addDotToEnd());
```

Note that

- Variables declared with `var` on the top level get put on the global object, but variables declared with `let` or `const` don't
- Strings are immutable - you can't change an existing string, you have to return a *new* string with the new contents